# Enable user-select on `ol li ::marker` to avoid losing numbers from numbered lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists, google-maps-markers

I face a problem with copying numbered lists (`<ol>`) from a chat application. When I copy the text, it doesn't include `::marker` numbers. This makes the list items lose context, as numbers represent the order of content.

I know CSS `::marker` pseudo-element isn't selectable by default, but I seek a workaround. The chat application often generates ordered lists, and users need to copy entire text, numbers included. It's not my app so I need to override CSS using the Stylus Chrome extension, I can't change their HTML or JS.

Does anyone know a way to select `::marker` content, or keep `ol li` list numbers during text copy?

Here's a basic example:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
</ol>
```

Here's my 1st attempted CSS:

```css
::marker {
  user-select: all;
}
```

This CSS still leaves out `::marker` numbers when I copy a numbered list, so the issue persists across modern browsers.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and thank you in advance for any help!

Bion

Comment: Can't you simply change it to `ul` add numbers manually?

Comment: sure, i can use bullet points on *my* lists, but I can't force other folks in the chat website to use them. and i just want to tinker with the css so i can copy paste their numbers when i copy paste their lists

Comment: Ok, but those numbers aren't part of their chat in the first place. Generated content (pseudo elements, markers etc) aren't part of the content so all those approaches will fail.

Comment: I totally disagree Salman, because in my experience when you number an outline, you want to keep the numbers. it's a basic obvious required feature for HTML + CSS end users to be able to copy numbers along with their numbered lists IMHO, regardless of implementation details about pseudo element markers or whatever. if i write an outline in any other system, the numbers copy with it. but not in OL LI ? Seems backward. we ought to have a way to toggle it on and off. Otherwise, copying isn't copying, since it converts numbered lists to walls of text!

Comment: `ol li ::marker { user-select: all }` is the obvious thing which ought to "just work" for this, but it doesn't, and there is no good reason or argument for that to not work. the purpose of the question is to figure out how to do that, so please either help me answer the question or leave me alone; Rather than attempt to invalidate the question with "We've always done it that way" (a dangerous fallacy), can you just answer the question with the CSS needed to user-select ::marker ? Just because ::marker doesn't user-select doesn't make it correct or desired behavior

Comment: Contrary to my point above, seems like css specs do say that pseudo `content:` should be accessible. I just don't know if browsers implement it or not.